# Creation of graph with networkx according to column value of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp': [1,2,3,4,1], 
               'name_emp': ['x','y','z','w','x'], 
               'donnated_value':[1100,11000,500,300,1000],
               'refound_value':[22000,22000,50000,450,90]
            })
df['return_percentagem'] = 100 * 
df['refound_value']/df['donnated_value']
df['classification_roi'] = ''

def comunidade(i):

    if i < 50:
        return 'Bad Investment'
    elif i >=50 and i < 100:
        return 'Median Investment'
    elif i >= 100:
        return 'Good Investment'

df['classification_roi'] = df['return_percentagem'].map(comunidade)
df
```

The nodes would be the 'id_emp'. There will be a connection between two nodes if they have the same 'id_emp' but with distinct classifications in the 'classification_roi' column or if they have the same rank in the 'classification_roi' column. In short, the nodes have a connection if they have the same id or if they are in the same classification in the column 'classification_roi'

I do not have much practice with networkx and what I'm trying is far from ideal:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'id_emp', 'return_percentagem')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Every help is welcome.

Comment: are the values ​​of the 'return_percentage' column. I want 'id_emp' with values ​​below 50 in the 'return_percentage' column to have connection to each other, and so with the other groups.

Comment: From this data what should the network look like?

Comment: Why do you have two `id_emp`s with value `1`? Are they two nodes or one?

Comment: They are two nodes, and are grouped according to the range of 'result_percentage' values. I want to create communities from the value of this column. For example: Communities with 'result_percentage' value above 100, community between 51 and 100.

Comment: @ScottBoston I think it's better explained

Comment: @QuangHoang 
I think it's better explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I am not using `from_pandas_edgelist`. Instead, list comprehensions and for-loops:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import itertools

G = nx.Graph()

# use index to name nodes, rather than id_emp, otherwise
# multiple nodes would end up having the same name
G.add_nodes_from([a for a in df.index])

#create edges:
#same employee edges
for ie in set(df['id_emp']):
    indices = df[df['id_emp']==ie].index
    G.add_edges_from(itertools.product(indices,indices))

# same classification edges
for cr in set(df['classification_roi']):
    indices = df[df['classification_roi']==cr].index
    G.add_edges_from(itertools.product(indices,indices))

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Optional: colouring, to distinguish nodes.

```
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('coloured by id_emp')
nx.draw(G, node_color=df['id_emp'], cmap='viridis')

plt.subplot(122)

color_mapping = { 
    'Bad Investment': 0,
    'Median Investment': 1,
    'Good Investment':2}

plt.title('coloured by classification_roi')
nx.draw(G, node_color=df['classification_roi'].replace(color_mapping), cmap='RdYlBu')
```

[image]